# How to access several $http.get() and store their responses in an array using for loop and access the array

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

My code is like below,

```
// calls only the API and return it
s.getArchSales = function (url, qParam) {
    // set the request object
    var req = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': securitySrv.header, // set the header
        'url': url,
        'data': qParam
    }
    return $http(req)
}

var portFolioMixArray = []
for(var i = 0; i < tech.length; i++ ){
 s.getArchSales(url, query)
    .then(function (response) {
      portFolioMixArray.push(response.data)
    })
 }
```

`tech` is also an array which is also computed dynamically

Now when I `console.log(portFolioMixArray)` it shows *Array[0]* with an extension symbol at the left like below, 
[image]

I can't access the Array elements. How can I access it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did console.log, at that time the http response was not yet received and the array was empty and hence you were not able to access the array elements.

Later, the response was received and array was updated. That's why you see the blue icon with the message.

Comment: That I understand. But how to access the array

Comment: I think for your use case of multiple promises in a loop, using `$q.all` makes more sense. Look at the example here - https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q#qall

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using `portFolioMixArray[0]`

if you want bind the values in html, then you need use `ng-repeat`
You should use the object in $scope

like

```
$scope.portFolioMixArray = []
for(var i = 0; i < tech.length; i++ ){
 s.getArchSales(url, query)
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.portFolioMixArray.push(response.data)
    })
 }
```

//html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in portFolioMixArray">{{item .YourObjectNmae}}</div>
```

Comment: portFolioMixArray[0] shows undefined. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you should understand the concept of promise, in Angular you can use $q.(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

You can access your array like this:

```
var promises = tech.map(function (item) {
    return s.getArchSales(url, query).then(function (response) {
        portFolioMixArray.push(response.data)
    })
}
$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log(portFolioMixArray);
}
```